# number of subsets that has no two consecutive elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this question in my combinatorics course. Find the number of subsets of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that it doesn't contain any two consecutive elements. **Using Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion**.

I tried doing it by subtracting all subsets that have 2 or more consecutive elements but the solution is not taking care of repetitions and It is very confusing. Can someone suggest a way to do this by PIE?

**Attempt:** Going by the suggestion given by @Wuestenfux and this thought also crossed my mind that takes $A_i$ to be the set of subsets containing $i$ and $i+1$.
But to calculate $$\sum_{I\subseteq[n],I\ne\phi}(-1)^{|I|}|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|$$ let for $|I|=k$,  where $k$ is an integer in $1,2,...,n$. to calculate $|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|$ for this, we have to take cases on the $k$ integers we choose because all will give different values.

Example: If $k=2$, $I$ could be $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,3\}$ giving $|A_1\bigcap A_2|=2^{n-3}$ whereas ,$|A_1\bigcap A_3|=2^{n-4}$.

So my question now is how to find a general $|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|$ if $|I|=k$

Comment: PIE will handle the repetitions, for example let $E(z)$ denotes the counting of a consecutive $z$ observed and $n=3$, then $E(\{1,2\})+E(\{2,3\})-E(\{1,2\}\land\{2,3\})$ will appears in PIE and count $\{1,2,3\}$ exactly once($1+1-1=1$). Notice that $E(\{1,2\}\land\{2,3\})=E(\{1,2,3\})$, which is your consideration of "have 2 *or more* consecutive elements". And my $E(\{1,2\})$ is exactly $|A_1|$ in @Wuestenfux's answer.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel The question in the link is asking permutations of the e$n+1$ digits, but this question is about the total number of subsets, ie. all digits need not be present in the subset.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and define $A_i$ as the set of subsets of $A$ which contain $i$ and $i+1$, where $1\leq i\leq n-1$. Using inclusion-exclusion, you will find the cardinality of
$P(A)\setminus (\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i)$.

Added hint: You have to consider the cardinality of $\bigcap_{j\in I} A_j$ for each nonzero index set $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: yes, I was asking exactly that in the question which I further edited. I asked how we could do what you said in the added hint.